# SAS Guide read the latest file from temporary folder

Tags: import, sas

I have a task to import the latest uploaded file from our portal. I managed to upload all nessesary files into temporary lib using spicial import addon.

My code looks like:

`%let Location_from1=\\*****\DavWWWRoot\sites\IDR\;
%let Location_to1=%sysfunc(pathname(work));`

Then I use the addon and import several files into temporary folder like:

`/u00/tmp/SAS_work9B07000013FF_asukr01lv/SAS_work3786000013FF_asukr01lv/*****1.xlsx
/u00/tmp/SAS_work9B07000013FF_asukr01lv/SAS_work3786000013FF_asukr01lv/*****2.xlsx
/u00/tmp/SAS_work9B07000013FF_asukr01lv/SAS_work3786000013FF_asukr01lv/*****3.xlsx`

Now i need to find out the latest one and import it to my work. How can i do it?

Comment: Is SAS 'GUIDE' supposed to mean: SAS Enterprise Guide?

Comment: How would you identify the latest one manually. Is there a date in the file name? Are you referencing the last modified or created date?

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1wyzhuyjmwfsun1iwqnluezhql9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Yes, I mean SAS Enterprise Guide. And there is no date in filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the path it looks like you are using *nix. In this case you can get the latest file using shell script:

```
filename latest pipe "cd &Location_to1.; ls -t1 | egrep 'xlsx$' | head -n 1";

data _null_;
    infile latest truncOver;
    input fileName $200.;
    call symput('latestFile', strip(fileName));
run;
```

A system-agnostic solution based on [Bruno_SAS](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/without-using-quot-pipe-quot-option/m-p/217936/highlight/true#M16397) code:

```
%macro getLatestFile(dirName=, extType=, out=);
    %let extType = %upcase(&extType);

    * Get the list of all files with the last modification date;
    data allFiles;
        length msg $ 256 fileRef $ 8 dirName $ 1024 fileName $ 256 fullName $ 1281;

        rc_check=fileexist("&dirName");

        if rc_check=0 then
            do;
                putlog "ERROR: &sysMacroname &dirName does not exist";
                stop;
            end;

        rc_assign=fileName(fileRef, "&dirName");

        dirId=dopen(fileRef);

        if dirId=0 then
            do;
                msg=sysmsg();
                putlog "ERROR: &sysMacroname could not open &dirName as directory";
                putlog msg;
                rc_assign=fileName(fileRef);
                stop;
            end;

        n_files=dnum(dirId);

        do i=1 to n_files;
            fileName=dread(dirId, i);

            if upcase(scan(fileName, -1, "."))="&extType" then
                do;
                    dirName="&dirName";
                    fullName=catx("/", dirName, fileName);
                    n_match + 1;
                    rc_fnOpen=fileName('current', "&dirName" || fileName);
                    fileId=fOpen('current');
                    lastChanged=input(fInfo(fileId, 'Last Modified'), datetime.);
                    format lastChanged datetime.;
                    rc_close=fClose(fileId);
                    rc_fnClose=fileName('current');
                    output;
                end;
        end;

        dirId=dclose(dirId);
        rc_assign=fileName(fileRef);
        msg=catx(" ", "NOTE: &sysMacroname found", n_match, 
            "files that match &extType");
        putlog msg;
        keep dirName fileName fullName lastChanged;
    run;

    * Keep only the latest file;
    proc SQL outobs=1;
    create table &out. as
        select fullName
        from allFiles
        order by lastChanged desc
    ;
    quit;

%mend;

%getLatestFile(dirName= %sysFunc(pathName(work)), extType=xlsx, out=latest);
```

Comment: I have a problem using this code, it gives me message "This account is 
currently not available". Tried to do it with files on PC - the same result.

Comment: Is it possible that XCMD option is disabled in your settings (you should be able to check it in sasHelp.vOption)? Basically it will not allow you to use pipes in this case. The code will not work on PC SAS, because it is *nix specific. For PC SAS (Windows) you can try something like "dir &Location_to1. | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1" instead of 'cd', but I did not check it myself.

Comment: I added system-independent solution, which should work for any OS.

Comment: Thx a lot. It works, but I see that in table allFiles lastChanged is empty( I  added `lastCreated=input(fInfo(fileId, 'Create Time'), datetime.);
                    format lastCreated datetime.;` - the same result(

Comment: Hm, really strange. So if you do lastCreated=fInfo(fileId, 'Create Time') or lastChanged=fInfo(fileId, 'Last Modified') the values will be also missing? What is your OS? Have your run it in SAS EG or PC SAS?

Comment: I was checking it always in Linux (with SAS Studio), but according to the documentation it should also work for Windows.

Comment: But I think your SAS EG is connecting to some server, where actually the code is run.  My only guess that it is some kind of z/OS which does not support those attributes. Because from what I saw both Unix and Linux OSes supported this attribute.

Comment: How can i check it? there is also option fOpen, that can also either work or not?

Comment: To check your OS, you can run 
***proc setInit; run;*** and check the log.
You can also print sysScp and sysScpL macro variables.
What do you mean by "there is also option fOpen'? The problem is not that fInfo does not work, it looks like it has a limited number of attributes which can be shown. I guess if you specify 'File Size' in fInfo, you will get it.

Comment: I ran it, I have LIN X64. Moreover, I've tried this code from this pagehttps://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1wyzhuyjmwfsun1iwqnluezhql9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en , and the result is, that It shows me size, ModifyDT is the datetime I imported the file to server, and CreateDT is empty. fileSize=finfo(fileId,'File Size'); also shows me nothing.

Comment: Well, SAS is unpredictable on different platforms or some OS specific settings are causing that issue. I have the same LIN X64 and it works fine for me. You wrote that you can get the ModifyDT value. This is all you need and in the solution I've used the 'Last Modified' attribute. Am I missing something? I'm wondering if you have SAS Grid, I would not be surprised that all these issues are caused by it.

Comment: In fact, its date and time I move my files from local folder to temporary. And I move all files at the same time, thats why it doesn't help me. I asked several ppl at my work, mb they will help me with peemission or smth else. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry the solution did not help. We unfortunate people using SAS must help each other :)

Comment: особенно русские)я к слову уточнил у коллег из IT, это вероятно ограничение между Линуксом, на котором стоит САС, и виндой...не передается информация о создании файла(

Comment: Ha, indeed :) Well, IT likes putting limitations, don't they.